# Dynamically adding namespace to SOAP Envelope in Java

Tags: java, soap

I am new to all of this but I am trying to create a SOAP message and get stuck at the off, I am using Java 8 and the standard javax.xml.soap classes but seem unable to add namespaces to the Envelope

```
MessageFactory factory  = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage message     = factory.createMessage();
SOAPPart part       = message.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope envelope   = part.getEnvelope();

envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration( "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

If I try this at runtime I get the following error
NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this now by creating the required envelope definition as an XML String and then setting the SOAPPart content using that string